# Reverse Polish boolean operations with stack size of one.

Tags: boolean-algebra, polish-notation

I'd like to evaluate a boolean expression:

$AB + CD + ... + YZ$

But the engine with which I can evaluate expressions operates in reverse polish with a stack size of one. For example, I can evaluate $AB + C$ as:

$((\text{A B and}) \text{ C or})$

But for $AB + CD$ and other more complex statements, I'm not sure whether or not it is possible to evaluate with a single stack slot.

So my questions are: What are the limits of a stack size of one when evaluating arbitrary AND/OR boolean expressions? Is it possible to re-factor my original expression into single serial operations?

Comment: But $A(B+\bar ACD)$ is not the same as $AB+CD$

Comment: No? Maybe I am rustier on this stuff than I thought...

Comment: See what happens if $A$ is false and $C,D$ are true

Comment: Doh! I will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an old HP calculator or something? They worked on RPN. But they also had another memory location where you could store partial results while you worked up the other side.